# jQuery last child selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is not working and I don't know why. I have tried it in the console it works, but when I change my js codes it does not work.

```
$('#recipe-table td:last-child').width();
```

How can I get it the correct way?

this is the html

```
           <div id="div-lists">  
                    <div id="div-recipe-table">
                    <table class="" id="recipe-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody>                                
                                    <tr class="recipe-list" data-ng-repeat="recipe in recipe_data" ng-click="recipe_click(recipe.CodeListe,recipe.Name)">
                                        <td id="td-img{{recipe.CodeListe}}">
                                            <center>
                                                <span id="img{{recipe.ID}}X">
                                                    <a id="{{recipe.ID}}" href="javascript:void(0);">
                                                        <img  ng-if="recipe.Pictures !==''" fallback-src="images/default.png" ng-src="{{recipe.Pictures}}" class="images" id="img{{recipe.ID}}"/><img  ng-if="recipe.Pictures===''" class="images" src="images/default.png" id="img1"/>
                                                    </a>
                                                </span>
                                            </center>
                                        </td>
                                 <!-- I want to get The width of this <td> -->
                                        <td class="recipes"> 
                                            <div id="div-recipe-name">
                                                <strong>{{recipe.Name}}</strong></div>
                                        </td>
                                 <!-- Until here
                                    I already tried using $('.recipes').width(); but it returns 0 -->
                                    </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                    <div id="div-list-loading"></div>
                    <div id="div-list-noresults">{{ui_translation.UIT[171610]}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: make sure that the html elements are loaded in the dom when you run the script from your js file

Comment: `:last-of-type` perhaps? Or `$('#recipe-table td').last()`.

Comment: `$('#recipe-table td').last().width()` should work too

Comment: You will receive better feedback if you also include your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('#recipe-table td:last').width();
```

From the [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)

> While :last matches only a single element, :last-child can match more
>   than one: one for each parent.

Since you have already tried `$('.recipes').width();` does the following provide you any results:

```
$('.recipes').each(function (index, elem) {
    alert($(this).width());
});
```

Comment: I actually need the one that selects multiple child. last-child it is.I'm still trying to solve it.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the width of multiple elements?

Comment: the recipe is actually a <td> of a table. I want to get the width of the td, but I can't. I already tried all you guys suggested but it returns null.

Comment: Maybe try adding a snippet of the `HTML` markup to the question and we might have a better idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try below jQuery

You can use [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/) method constructs a new jQuery object from the last element in that set.

```
$('#recipe-table td').last().width();
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6epasfnq/)**

Comment: See the fiddle demo how it's working. might problem with other code. share code in JSFIDDLE